# Take screenshot within app

Tags: android, screenshot

I have an application that overrides the `onKeyDown`.
This is the method:

```
    @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // my stuff     
       }
}
```

Now if I try to take a screenshot in my app, the **long press** of the button necessary to take the screenshots, doesn't seem to work.
Is there a **not so painful** way to be able to take screenshots again?

P.S. Sorry for my English

Comment: what are you trying to do.?? not get your problem.

Comment: override onBackPress insteand of onKeyDown. What's your issue?

Comment: do you mean you have to long press back button to take a screenshot ?

Comment: sorry again for bad expaination: my back button is overrided for other needs. And to take a screenshot i need to press that arrow + the power button. (Galaxy Tab). Now: if my back arrow is linked with my method, how can i take a screenshot?

Comment: Try with the power and the volume down buttons on the side of the case to take screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown( int keyCode, KeyEvent event ) {
    if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ) {
      event.startTracking();
      return true; 
    }
    return super.onKeyDown( keyCode, event );
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onKeyUp( int keyCode, KeyEvent event ) {
    if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ) {
      //Your stuff. (Handle what you want on short press).      
      return true; 
    }

    return super.onKeyUp( keyCode, event );
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onKeyLongPress( int keyCode, KeyEvent event ) {
    if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ) {
      //Handle what you want in long press.
      return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyLongPress( keyCode, event );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); //Root layout of your APP
Bitmap bmp=Layout.getDrawingCache(); //Screen shot bitmap
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Eclipse- DDMS View  to take Screenshot in this case.This is easy.

Comment: I would, but my customer can't do that :P